# Put each element of an array, in a cell of a table created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a table using javascript. However, I would like each of the cells (`td`) in the table to display each element in my array, in order of the elements in the array. 
This is the array with the words in it:

```
var Myarray=['Anime','Demon','Black','Death','Beast','Tokyo','Manga','Titan','Ghoul'];
```

Here is my Javascript code so far:

```
function display_array(Myarray){
        var body = document.body,
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '100px';
    tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
    var arrayLength = Myarray.length;
    var sqroot=Math.sqrt(arrayLength);

    for(var i = 0; i < sqroot; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < sqroot; j++){
            if(i == sqroot && j == sqroot){
                break;
            } else {
                var td = tr.insertCell();


                for(var q = 0; q < arrayLength; q++){
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Myarray[q]));
                }

                td.style.border = "1px solid black";
                if(i == 1 && j == 1){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '1');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);

}
```

With this code, my table looks like this:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
 |AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|AnimeDemonBlackDeathBeastTokyoMangaTitanGhoul|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like my table to look like this:

```
___________________
|Anime|Demon|Black|
-------------------
|Death|Beast|Tokyo|
-------------------
|Manga|Titan|Ghoul|
-------------------
```

Comment: Note that things will break if there the array length isn't a perfect square.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Lr6tbm7/

Comment: Your `if(i == sqroot && j == sqroot)` statement is completely useless, as neither would ever be the case due to your loop conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var q = 0; q < arrayLength; q++){
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Myarray[q]))
}
```

This loops thru and create a textNode for each element. If you want one element use `Myarray[index]`; in this case index is `i * sqroot + j`.

```
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Myarray[i * sqroot + j]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The logic does make sense! But, I've tried it, and it repeats that specific element in the cell 9 times (the length of the array).

Comment: @StephenGevanni Remove the inner for loop with the `q`.

Comment: Thanks so much! If it's fine, can you please explain the i * sqroot + j part? Much appreciated.

Comment: @StephenGevanni You have `i` as the row part and `j` as the column part. So you multiply `i` by the row length, `sqroot`, to get to the right row then add `j` to get to the right column within the row.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!! You cannot imagine how happy I am!!!!!! I really appreciate it!!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why you're using sqroot, but if you want a 3 column table containing each item in your array, something like this would do it:

```
var tr, td;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0)
        tr = tbl.insertRow();
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Myarray[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable **outside** your function called **index**

```
var index =0;
```

Then replace your else code with

```
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Myarray[index]));
            td.style.border = "1px solid black";
            if(i == 1 && j == 1){
                td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '1');
            }
            index++;
```